# Navigate to a new page in React? Not SPA

Tags: reactjs, navigation

Recently started using React and I have an issue that is perhaps very basic.

I simply want to click a button and get taken to a new page. I.e go from login screen to the home screen. It seems that all the answers I find online recommend using `react-router` but that seems to be for Single Page Applications? I want to use actual new pages when navigating.

I have my login function

```
 login = () => {
       //I want to go to another page
    }
```

and on my button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => this.login()}>Sign in</button>
```

I guess the problem is that I only have one HTML file (see file structure below), and I would need to have an html file each for every page?

[image: File structure]

Is there any way to do this, or is SPA the way to go with React?

Comment: Does `window.location = '/foo.html'` (or whatever) inside your function  work?

Comment: I edited my question with some new information.  I currently only have one Index.html file which holds my entire app, so there's nothing to link to